connection error for connecting to API server in kubernetes
I have error connection to api-server in k8s.
When i run "kubectl proxy &" and after that i run below command
curl http://192.168.56.101:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/emad
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.56.101 port 8001: Connection refused

but when i run below command,everything is fine.
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/emad
```.
my localhost ip is 192.168.56.101 and firewall is off and selinux is permissive.

I would appreciate if anyone can help me on this subject.


Does it work with curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/emad?

What is the result of netstat -an|grep LISTEN|grep 8001?

@user202311   yes,it works with  http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/emad

@RomeoNinov  the output is  "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5766/kubectl"  but i also test "kubectl proxy --address 192.168.56.101 --port 8001 &" command and the output was  "tcp        0      0 192.168.56.101:8001     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8347/kubectl" but again does not work

@RomeoNinov I got forbidden error from second command.

@EmadKhavaninzadeh,  add the text in the question

The first command (kubectl proxy) seems to be working fine. Note that the localhost IP is 127.0.0.1, not 192.168.56.101 (“my localhost ip is 192.168.56.101”). For the second command (with --address 192.168.56.101), try adding --accept-hosts '.*' to the command.
